# Windows 10 Slow Boot Time, require help to check Windows Performance Analyzer Logs

Tags: windows-10, ssd, m.2, wpa

I recently migrated (cloned) Windows 10 from a SSD to a M.2 PCIe SSD. Everything works and runs fine, but I realized Windows requires ~85 to 115 Seconds to boot.
I'm not sure if it takes so long only since migration or if it already did before as I used to mostly use Wake-on-Lan to start the PC minutes before I went to the PC and therefor didn't care.
However, I spent most of the day trying to find my way through Windows Performance Analyzer-Logs for the reason of the long boot time, but by now I kind of feel lost in it.
On my research I found similar threads on superuser.com and I hope someone more expierenced could take a look into my issue as well and/or is willing to explain me how to track down the issue myself.
Link to WPA-Logs in .etl file format: mega.nz/#!k4lWFSRK!huCDHY-GUqEWiGVstEz2BPNBb-3noELi2FWJ2YghaHU

Comment: That seems about par for Windows 10 cold-boot time, particularly because some anti-malware apps (e.g. Defender) do a prescan before machine is usable. Hibernate should open faster. Or try another OS, e.g. Linux, which I find boots about three times faster.

Comment: Common issues here.....https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/4-tips-fix-slow-boot-windows-10-solved/

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Defender is disabled, Hibernation is often used, but it doesn't help with the need of restarts. Another OS is not an option for this machine.

Comment: @Moab These Common issues do not apply here, Fast Startup is generally disabled as it makes no sense on a SSD, even less on a M.2. There are no processes with high startup impact. The issue is somewhere long before startup processes are started anway.
Graphics card drivers are updated constantly, doing a clean install of Windows is not an option right now.

Comment: In this case, I think looking at all the process and ordering by the start time is most revealing.  Your trace shows: https://imgur.com/a/1v2NrBF So, nearly 50 seconds passes between autochk.exe and smss.exe (800) starting. autochk.exe only runs for 0.7 seconds and then exits so that's not the issue.  Then I'd turn to drivers and the system process around this time and I see 360fsflt.sys, which seems to be related to 360 Anti-Virus?  Could you rename this driver and reboot?  I assume it's under \windows\system32\drivers\ I haven't looked further.

Comment: @HelpingHand Thanks for pointing me into that direction. Yes, this driver is part of 360 Total Security Essential. I uninstalled it completely and verified 360fsflt.sys was deleted as well. Regarding the boot time it sadly changed nothing.

Comment: OK, the other one I see in stacks aroud this time that I'm not full aware of is avmaura.sys. I guess from these people: https://en.avm.de/ Do you know much about it?  If the functionality it provides is non essentialt it wouldn't hurt to rename the file \windows\system32\drivers\avmaura.sys and reboot to see the time, you can then rename it back if not or seek an upgrade if it does help?

Comment: @HelpingHand avmaura.sys belongs to the german router manufacturer AVM and it's function is to allow the local use of devices that are plugged into the network router. Had it tested a while ago and then forgot about it. I just uninstalled it, but it didn't changed anything either.
I have diificulties to follow your way through the logs. I can easily look through WPA's System Activity/Processes-Logs, but I don't know where to look at to see the driver traces you were pointing to.

Comment: Given this as a starting point: https://imgur.com/a/SvJjFkk I think we can zoom in to between 18 and 66 seconds to see what is happening. Then just using sampled CPU usage view, you can see the stacks of the system process to see the modules, in this case drivers as it's the system process. https://imgur.com/a/xAjXLXN  It's there I see the 2 360 drivers, avmaura.sys, I also see rxfcv.sys - Romex Software's PrimoCache Driver. I figure one approach is to elimate non MS drivers that aren't essential to boot with that are started and are on some stack around this time.

Comment: @HelpingHand Thanks for all your help, I already learned quite alot by it today.
So far I got rid of most of the non-MS-drivers around in this time area, but none of them had any impact on the boot time.
https://abload.de/img/08-02-2019.23-06-23.bdgjyh.png
Thats everything left for now and it's getting hard to think of what driver to uninstall next. I'm sure I shouldn't touch that Marvell Driver (mvs91xx.sys) and that Intel Driver (iaStorAC.sys). And except for that Nv-Driver and the 360*.sys there are no non-MS-Drivers left.
mega.nz/#!5lknXYKK!TFO0fLIp4QsHObpl4UIBfsJ6M0ano9QhmpEQwYxZAb0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw your boot trace and it seems that the boot delay you experience is caused by the hibernation file (hiberfil.sys)

In the CPU precise graph you can see that the SMSS process spent 45s waiting on the PoPEnableHiberFile function.

[image: CPU Precise Graph]

This is correlated by the File I/O graph where you can see SMSS process spending 43s accessing C:\hiberfil.sys

[image: File I/O Graph]

You need to disable the hibernation in order to delete the c:\hiberfil.sys => **powercfg -h off**

then restart your computer and see if that help.

if you need to turn the hibernation back issue this command => **powercfg -h on**

Comment: Wow, though I recently temporarily had already turned that off and on for other reasons, it actually really was the cause for the issue.
Turning it off and on again fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Glad that you fixed it :)